# "It's getting close to goodbye"

Tags: grammaticality, conversation

Is this grammatically correct? Is there anything wrong with that sentence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's grammatically correct. The use of "goodbye" is unusual but perfectly understandable.

Comment: It doesn't need quotes around it?

Comment: Not unless you're planning on killing them.

Comment: @Sam I'm in tears. You're going to get me fired.